# How to wrap JSX in parent div with shortcut in VS code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

I'm buidling a React app in VS code and was was wondering if there was some sort of snippet or extension that would allow me to wrap JSX in a parent tag without having to type to opening tag then moving to the end of the piece of JSX I want to wrap in order to place the closing tag. For example I would have a bunch of paragraphs:

```
<p>Hi there</p>
<p>How are you?</p>
<p>More paragraphs...</p>
...
```

That I would want to wrap a div around so it would be like this:

```
<div className="some class">
    <p>Hi there</p>
    <p>How are you?</p>
    <p>More paragraphs...</p>
    ......
</div>
```

But I find uncomfortable at times, what would have is I would type `<div>` then `</div>` would automatically show up in the same line, then I would cut it and paste it at the end of all the `<p>` tags. So I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this?

I tried searching for extensions but could not find any.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily.

1. Just select the JSX code block.
2. Open command palate `ctrl+shift+p`
3. Search for `wrap with` keyword, and then you will find something like emmet wrap with abbreviation.
4. Press enter after that you can write and emmet expression eg:- to wrap with div with className="some class" then you can write `.some.class`

if you want you can assign a shortcut to the command

Answer (score 0):

VS Code comes with built in support for Emmett. Emmett has a handy "wrap with abbreviation" command you can see [here](https://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/).

I set up my editor to recognize `cmd+w` as the "wrap with abbreviation" command.

1. Cmd + shift + p to open Command Palette
2. Search for "Open Keyboard Shortcuts"
3. Search for "wrap with abbreviation"
4. Add your keybinding

[image]

---

### Bonus

You can set up a similar keyboard shortcut to remove a tag (unwrap). The action is called "Emmet: Remove Tag".